# How to calculate the eigenvector corresponding to zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can the eigenvector corresponding to zero eigenvalue be found out? I was trying with the following simple matrix in Matlab:

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & -2 & 3 \\ 2 & -3 & 4 \\ 3 & -4 & 5 \end{array}\right] \; .$$

In matlab computations, the matrix seemed nearly singular with one of the eigenvalues very close to zero (3e-15). That means the usual shifted inverse power methods for finding out the unit eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue won't work. But Matlab returns an eigenvector corresponding to 0. How? Basically, I would like to develop a program to compute this eigenvector given any singular matrix. What algorithm should I use?

Edit: (1) Edited to reflect that the 'nearly singular' comment was corresponding to Matlab calculation.
(2) Edited to specify the actual question.

Comment: If all the elements of a matrix are integers, as here, then the determinant is an integer. So 'nearly singular' is impossible!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This matrix is singular, the determinant is zero, so it has an eigenvector for eigenvalue $0$. Nothing mysterious there -- you might want to check the calculation that made you think it was only nearly singular.

As for how to find eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$: They are just the solutions of the homogeneous system of linear equations corresponding to this matrix, $Ax=0$, so you can use e.g. Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mentioned "nearly singular" because, in matlab the eigenvalue seemed to 3e-15 with long formatting. I of course realize that the matrix is completely singular, but I was wondering why Matlab had it that way which made it seem nearly singular as opposed to completely singular. I will rephrase the original question to reflect that.

Comment: Just edited OP as mentioned above, and change the question to "I would like to develop a program to compute this eigenvector given any singular matrix. What algorithm should I use?" Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @Samik: "in MATLAB the eigenvalue seemed to 3e-15 with long formatting." - because MATLAB uses floating point arithmetic; thus, don't expect supposedly zero results to be \*exactly\* zero.

Comment: People keep saying to use Gaussian Elimination to solve Ax=0, but doing that just gives you x=0 as a solution, it doesn't yield the actual zero-eigenvector.

Comment: @JerryGuern: No – if the matrix has eigenvalue $0$, solving $Ax=0$ actually gives you the corresponding eigenvector(s). An eigenvalue $0$ implies singularity, so the system $Ax=0$ has an infinity of solutions in this case, not just the obvious one $x=0$.

Answer (score 9):

A matrix $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$. This is equivalent to the existence of a nonzero vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. This is equivalent to the matrix $A-\lambda I$ having nontrivial nullspace, which in turn is equivalent to $A-\lambda I$ being singular (determinant equal to $0$).

In particular, $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvector *if and only if* $\det(A)=0$. If the matrix is "nearly singular" but not *actually* singular, then $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue.

As it happens,
$$\begin{align*}
\det(A) &= \left|\begin{array}{rr}
-3 & \hphantom{-}4\\
-4 & 5
\end{array}\right| + 2\left|\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 4\\
3 & 5
\end{array}\right| + 3\left|\begin{array}{rr}
\hphantom{-}2 & -3\\
3 & -4
\end{array}\right|\\
&= \Bigl(-15 + 16\Bigr) + 2\Bigl( 10 - 12\Bigr) + 3\Bigl(-8+9\Bigr)\\
&= 1 - 4 + 3 = 0,
\end{align*}$$
so the matrix is not "nearly singular", it is just plain singular.

The eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$ are found by solving the system $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. So, the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=0$ are found by solving the system $(A-0I)\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. That is: solve
$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcl}
x & - & 2y & + & 3z & = & 0            \\
2x & - & 3y & + & 4z & = & 0           \\
3x & - & 4y & + & 5z & = & 0.
\end{array}$$
The solutions (other than the trivial solution) are the eigenvectors. A basis for the solution space (the nullspace of $A$) is a basis for the eigenspace $E_{\lambda}$.

**Added.** If you know a square matrix is singular, then finding eigenvectors corresponding to $0$ is equivalent to solving the corresponding system of linear equations. There are plenty of algorithms for doing that: Gaussian elimination, for instance (Wikipedia even has pseudocode for implementing it). If you want numerical stability, you can also use Grassmann's algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I actually have slightly different requirement, and have modified the OP to reflect that. Basically, "I would like to develop a program to compute this eigenvector given any singular matrix. What algorithm should I use?"

Comment: @Samik: Solving systems of linear equations with integer coefficients can be done through Gaussian elimination, or the modification using Grassmann's algorithm (which avoids subtraction).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be the eigenvector corresponding to the eignevalue of $0$ for the matrix $\mathbf{A}$.  Since $\mathbf{Ax=0}$, we can see that the row space of $\mathbf{A}$ is perendicular to the eigenspace of $\mathbf{x}$.  Therefore, choose any two non-parallel row vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ and the cross product of them is the eigenvector.  For example if we caclulate and simplify $(1,-2,3) \times (2, -3, 4)$, we can obtain that $\mathbf{x}=(1,2,1)$.